# Slide Text In and Out

Tags: jquery

I am having issues with a slide in Text slider:

HTML:

```
<div id="textSlider">
    <ul>
         <li class="active">Doors | Windows | Showers</li>
         <li>Superb Fenestration | Superior Service</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#textSlider ul li').each(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.active').animate({'left': '0px'},500).delay(500).animate({'left': '-300px'},500);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }, 2000);

});
```

CSS:

```
#textSlider{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
ul li{
    position: relative;
    left: -300px;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sCsJV/39/)

What I need:

I want the first line to slide in, then out.
After the first line, the second one should do the same.

Then the function should repeat the whole process

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `setInterval`?  This will allow you to repeat something over and over

Comment: nope but I will, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change your JavaScript to:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.active').animate({'left': '0px'},500)
      .delay(500)
      .animate({'left': '0px'},500)
      .animate({'left':'-300px'},500)
      .removeClass('active')
      .siblings('li')
      .addClass('active');
}, 2000);
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/FV5jL/)

This will loop indefinitely every 2 seconds...

Keep in mind it'll only iterate over 2 elements (as shown on your example), if you need it to iterate over `n` number of elements, you can try this instead:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var $current = $('.active').animate({'left': '0px'},500)
        .delay(500)
        .animate({'left': '0px'},500)
        .animate({'left':'-300px'},500)
        .removeClass('active');

    if($current.next('li').length > 0) {
        $current.next('li').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $current.siblings('li:eq(0)').addClass('active');
    }
}, 2000);
```

Basically caching the current active element on the `$current` variable, using the `if` to check if there's another `<li>` after it, and it case there's none, going back to the first `<li>` to add the class `active`...

[**JSFiddle Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/FV5jL/4/)

**Finally**, If you want the first loop to be different than the other ones, you could do something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    loopList();
    setInterval(loopList,4000);
}, 1);

function loopList(){
    var $current = $('.active').animate({'left': '0px'},500)
    .delay(500).animate({'left': '0px'},500)
    .animate({'left':'-300px'},500)
    .removeClass('active');

    if($current.next('li').length > 0) {
        $current.next('li').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $current.siblings('li:eq(0)').addClass('active');
    }
}
```

In this case you'd be calling the first iteration from the `setTimeout` the first time right away (that's the reason for the 0 in this example), and then calling the `setInterval` which will loop every 4 seconds.

[**JSFiddle Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/5yhPf/)

Comment: for the OPs question this is the right answer - I have a feeling he will ask again for when he needs to iterate through a list of more than just 2 things.  Be on the lookout - otherwise, this is the answer he is looking for

Comment: Thank you very much. Great answer and your code is customizable as well. appreciate

Comment: One more question though - I want to make the interval longer, but the onset of the very first loop(starting one) should be much faster than the ones following...How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sCsJV/46/)

I moved your logic into a separate function. The animate() method takes a callback that will change the 'active' li then just call itself again. That gives you the infinite looping.

```
    function slide() {
    var activeElement = $('li.active');
    $('.active').animate({
        'left': '0px'
    }, 500).delay(500).animate({
        'left': '-300px'
    }, 500, function() {
        var nextActiveElement = activeElement.next('li');
        activeElement.removeClass('active');
        if (nextActiveElement.length < 1) {
            nextActiveElement = $('li').first();
        }
        nextActiveElement.addClass('active');
        slide();
    });
}

slide();
```

Comment: It works with as many li's as you want. Here is an update fiddle with 4 li's http://jsfiddle.net/sCsJV/47/

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Like the extra functionality

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jquery callback to archive this:

```
function showLi(){
$('#textSlider ul li').each(function(index, value){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(value).animate({'left': '0px'},500).delay(500).animate({'left': '0px'},500).animate({'left':'-300px'},500);
    }, index*2000);
});
}

showLi();
setInterval(showLi, $("#textSlider ul li").length*2000);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

The index is used to delay the timeout.

Check the forked fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Dwkz/4/